# auto ranking of rows when new data is added to sheet

Tags: google-sheets, ranking-functions

I have a Google sheet (sheet A) that gets fed from another sheet (sheet B). I am trying to auto-rank the rows when new data gets added to sheet B.

In the provided example screenshot (Example below), I use a formula for the "Points" column (M).  All it does is if Column L has a value of 1 then assign 7 points, if the value is 2, then assign 5 points, and if the value is 3 then assign 3 points. All others get 1 point. So every new row is added - the points are automatically assigned.

`={"Points";arrayformula(IF(L2:L="",,IF(L2:L=1,7,IF(L2:L=2,5,IF(L2:L=3,3,1)))))}`

The Rank column (L) uses the formula `=RANK(K2, K:K).`

I want a similar formula similar to points formula that ranks each of the new rows based on the Points.

I tried this formula but it does not work -

`={"Rankings";arrayformula(IF(K2:K="",,IF(K2:K>1,RANK(K2, K:K))))}`

Any help is appreciated.

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1NQx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this in Column L

```
={"Rank";BYROW(K2:K,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,RANK(ax,K2:K))))}
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Quick question - this formula skips the ranking. For example, if two participants have the same reps - both are ranked as #1 (rightfully so). But, unfortunately, the next participant on the list is ranked #3 - instead of #2. Can that be fixed?